# let div visible only when other div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to let one div visible only when other div/divs are visible or hovering menuButton.

Example:

When I hover one button of my menu, my "hiddenDiv" will appear. It should remain visible until I leave mouse from my hiddenDiv. After that the hiddenDiv becomes hidden again.

When I click on my hiddenDiv, when it is visible, another div will appear. My hiddenDiv should now remain visible, until the new div (i have multiple of these) is visible.

CODE

js:

```
$('#menuButton').mouseover(function() {
$('#pasMenTypy').hide();
$('#aktMenTypy').show();
$('.hiddenDiv').show();

$('.hiddenDiv').mouseover(function() {
$('.hiddenDiv').show();
    }); 
});

if($('#div1').is(':visible') || $('#div2').is(':visible') || $('#div3').is(':visible') || $('#div4').is(':visible') || $('#div5').is(':visible') || $('#div6').is(':visible') || $('#div7').is(':visible') || $('#div8').is(':visible')) {

$('.hiddenDiv').show();

} else {

$('.hiddenDiv').mouseout(function() {
$('.hiddenDiv').hide();
 });
}
```

It is currently showing the hiddenDiv, when hovering menuButton, but it is not remaining visible, when div1 or div2 or ... or div8 is visible. Can you help please?

EDIT: Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/ ... I want hiddenDiv appear when I am hovering menuButton1, when I am hovering menuButton2 I would like it to hide. When I click "blah" from hiddenDiv I want div1 to be visible and I also want my hidden div to remain visible. Now, only when I click on menuButton2 hiddenDiv will hide.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: Provide your HTML code also.If possible create a fiddle

Comment: Ok. Here it is:http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/ ... I want hiddenDiv appear when I am hovering menuButton1, when I am hovering menuButton2 I would like it to hide. When I click "blah" from hiddenDiv I want div1 to be visible and I also want my hidden div to remain visible. Now, only when I click on menuButton2 hiddenDiv will hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code like

```
    $('#menuButton').mouseover(function () {
        if ($('#div1').is(':visible') || $('#div2').is(':visible') || $('#div3').is(':visible') || $('#div4').is(':visible') || $('#div5').is(':visible') || $('#div6').is(':visible') || $('#div7').is(':visible') || $('#div8').is(':visible')) {
            $('.hiddenDiv').show();
        }
    });


    $('#menuButton').mouseout(function () {
        $('.hiddenDiv').hide();
    });
```

**Edit**

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/1/)

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/3/)

Comment: Ok. Here is fiddle to make sure you will understand what I would like to achieve:http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/ ... I want hiddenDiv appear when I am hovering menuButton1, when I am hovering menuButton2 I would like it to hide. When I click "blah" from hiddenDiv I want div1 to be visible and I also want my hidden div to remain visible. Now, only when I click on menuButton2 hiddenDiv will hide.

Comment: almost, but I forgot to mention that the hiddendiv should also disappear in the case when mouse cursor leaves it (hiddenDiv), but only if the div1 is not visible. If div1 is visible, hiddenDiv remains visible even though mouse cursor levas it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$('#menuButton').mouseover(function() {
    $('#pasMenTypy').hide();
    $('#aktMenTypy, .hiddenDiv').show();
});

if ($('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6, #div7, #div8').is(':visible')) {
    $('.hiddenDiv').show();
} else {
    $('.hiddenDiv').hide();
}
```